# Clearing data at a memory address

Tags: c++, memory

I had a look around and couldn't find much information on how to do this, but how can I clear the memory at a specific memory address?

Let's say I have a memory address value of: 0x12345 
What code would I need to write to cleanup whatever is in that space?

Preferably C or C++

Comment: If you do not already have a pointer to that address, or to a memory block containing that address, you probably don't want to alter that memory.

Comment: Where did you get that memory address from and does your OS even allow you to access it? Also what have you tried doing? (And what exactly do you mean by "cleanup"?

Comment: Answering this is irresponsible without you providing a rationale and assurances from your implementation that this is a valid thing to do.

Comment: I have a Java program and I want to clear the memory manually without GC, was planning on passing the memory addresses to a C++ program (or similar) and have it clean the memory.

Answer (score 2):

> What code would I need to write to cleanup whatever is in that space?

It depends.

To understand what code you need to write, first you need to know (1) what kind of object is stored in that address. Then, you must decide (2) what "cleanup" means in the context of that object. Once you have answers to those questions, then you can know what code needs to be written.

Example: Memory address `0x12345` contains an object of type `int`, and I want to "cleanup" that memory by setting the value of that integer to 0. Then You could write:

```
auto ptr = (int*)0x12345;
*ptr = 0;
```

If you don't know the answer to the questions 1 and 2, then you simply cannot "cleanup".

---

Note using an integer as a memory address is very dubious. How do we know there is an `int` object in that memory address? Usually you get addresses of objects by using the addressof operator. In that case the pointer should already be of appropriate type, so casting would be needed.

Comment: I know exactly what type of objects are in the memory locations. Is setting it to 0 how its supposed to be done?

Comment: @SurajKumar if the type of the object is `int` and if you intend to set the value to 0, then yes.

Comment: @SurajKumar then its value will not change.

Comment: So how would I remove the data? So that memory slot can be used for something/somebody else?

Comment: @SurajKumar that depends on how that memory was alllocated.

Answer (score -1):

sledgehammer answer to yr question (but I smell an XY problem)

```
unsigned char * p = (unsigned char*)0x12345;
*p = '\0';
```